# Trying to use editing mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to use edit mode to change vertices, faces, and edges, but whenever I select a single edge or face, etc., instead of moving that I just translate the entire object.

That is, instead of moving an edge down the entire object moves down, as if I am in object mode and translating.

Comment: Maybe you have all of the edges selected. Press A to deselect all and select only the one you want to move. Other thing to look for is that you are not using proportional editing. see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47684/why-is-there-a-white-circle-when-i-try-to-move-vertices/47686#47686

Comment: I don't have all edges selected, but i dont have proportional editing enabled. The problem though, is that when I turn off proportional editing, moving the edges moves only the edge and the faces don't follow. So if say i move the edge of a square, the face will stay in place and the edge im moving will go down. Basically creating an opening.

Comment: Is your proportional editing sphere of influence really big? Sometimes I will forget about how big my sphere of influence is and be surprised to find that all of the vertices move when I just wanted to move one.

Comment: Maybe you have accidentally duplicated your mesh or parts of it? Posting your .blend http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ file might help speed up a solution.

Comment: If you move an edge and the faces don't follow, it means that the edge in question is not connected to that face. Try this: Select all (**A**) pres **Ctrl** **V** and select remove doubles

Comment: How do I change my proportional editing sphere of influence?

Comment: scroll with the middle mouse button.